# warning: Could not find remote branch 1.4.0 to clone. fatal: Remote branch 1.4.0 not found in upstream origin

Tags: ios, git, github, cocoapods

I'm trying to download library's of [this](https://github.com/Yalantis/PullToMakeSoup) and [this](https://github.com/Yalantis/PullToMakeFlight) project using cocoapods but getting an error. Any one have any idea how i can fix it.
Thanks

```
Zafars-iMac:podinstall ZafarAhmad$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing PullToMakeFlight (1.1.2)
Installing PullToMakeSoup (1.2)
Installing PullToRefresher (1.4.0)

[!] Error installing PullToRefresher
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/Yalantis/PullToRefresh.git /var/folders/89/9pzfjxd50bs5_hy39qqm3m8r0000gn/T/d20160804-2979-vq368o --template= --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 1.4.0

Cloning into '/var/folders/89/9pzfjxd50bs5_hy39qqm3m8r0000gn/T/d20160804-2979-vq368o'...
warning: Could not find remote branch 1.4.0 to clone.
fatal: Remote branch 1.4.0 not found in upstream origin
```

> **This is my Podfile**

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '8.0'
inhibit_all_warnings!

target 'podinstall' do
  # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for podinstall

  target 'podinstallTests' do
    pod 'PullToMakeFlight'
    pod 'PullToMakeSoup'

    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'podinstallUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Comment: looks like dependencies are broken and you would have to just download the zip and add yourself

Comment: Thanks, But when i download zip, project it  not build because it need to add library, also same on demo project. Have you any idea how i can download library without `cocoapods` or any other method for fix it??   https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B29ka7gbDAYxbGNPWE1uT3dmdHM

Comment: [Drop by to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26424/iosandroidchaosoverflow)

Comment: PullToRefresh does not have any [tag](https://github.com/Yalantis/PullToRefresh/tags) or branch called 1.4.0 - you need to look into which of your dependencies require it transitively and ask that they fix it.